# Binding a callback in Backbone.js and Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have the following code:

```
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this);

    var callBack = function(res) {
      window.item = new Item(res);
      this.render();
    };

    _.bind(callBack, this);

    $.get('/item/parse', {
      uri: decodeURIComponent($.urlParam('uri')),
      title: decodeURIComponent($.urlParam('title'))
    },
      callBack
    );
  },
```

The intention is that render() should be called after the $.get function finishes. However, even after binding the callback function with _.bind, I still get "Object has no function render" in the console. Am I using bind incorrectly here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_.bind` returns a new function, so:

```
callBack = _.bind(callBack, this);
```

You can also use `_.bindAll`, but you have to call it *after* you define the function. Otherwise there are no functions at the time you call `_.bindAll`. Note that you have to use `this.callBack = ...` in that case, because otherwise `this` won't consist of any functions.

Using both `_.bind` and `_.bindAll` is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

I usually write a 'load' method on my model which I giva a callback as parameter. Then I call this method from the render() method in the view and do whatever I need to do in the callback function (of course, that callback is triggered in the model after the data has been loaded).