# Backbone: (Callback) function even not binding to Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I want updatePlays function to be called as a callback function when an AJAX call is successful. I thought that using underscore bind would let me refer 'this' as the Collection object that I actually want to update, but I'm having trouble here. When I get to the function that should update collection, it thinks that 'this' refers to 'window'.

In this situation, a Backbone Model has Backbone Collection, which are made from another backbone models.

in view:

```
SomeView: Backbone.View.extend({
  someFunction: function(e) {
    var field = this
    this.picker = new PlayPicker({
      field:field,
      model: new PlaySet({
        plays: new Collections.Plays({}),
        slot: field.model
      })
    })
  }
}) 

PlayPicker:Backbone.View.extend({
 ...
  refresh: function () {
    this.model.update()
  },
....
```

Collection that's part of model PlaySet

```
Plays:Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Play ,
  initialize: function () {
    plays = this
    _.bind(this.updatePlays, plays) // Where I thought I should bind
  },
  updatePlays: function (plays) {
    new_plays = []

    var i; 
    for (i = 0; i < plays.length; i++){
      new_plays.push(new Play({
        id: plays[i]["id"],
        text: plays[i]["text"]
      }));
    }

    this.reset(new_plays) // Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'reset' 
  }
})
```

Model PlaySet

```
PlaySet: Backbone.Model.extend({
  update: function() {
    this.get('slot').fetchAssociatedPlays(this.get('plays').updatePlays)
  },
})
```

Model Slot - does the AJAX call

```
Slot:Backbone.Model.extend({

  ...

  fetchAssociatedPlays: function(update) {
    thisModel = this
    $.ajax({
      url: thisModel.associatedPlaysURL(),
      success: function (collection) {
        update(collection)
      }
    })
  }})
```

Should this be achievable with underscore bind, and where/how would be the correct way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it is causing your problem, but declaring 'plays' without specifying 'var' before it is going to make the scope of 'plays' global I think which could cause problems, likewise with other variables you are missing the 'var'

Comment: Did that - and it should be something that I have done anyway, but I'm still getting the same error. Thanks though!

Comment: The answer here fixed my problem - ###See also > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349666/binding-a-callback-in-backbone-js-and-underscore-js?rq=1 - what to do now?

Comment: Ji Mun, you should post an answer to your own question and accept it so people don't keep reading it for no reason.

Comment: For some reason Stackoverflow is not letting me post right now... I'll take care of that once this bug goes away. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question has helped me fix my issue:
[Binding a callback in Backbone.js and Underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349666/binding-a-callback-in-backbone-js-and-underscore-js?rq=1)

```
callBack = _.bind(callBack, this);
```

It was that I need to use a function that is the result of binding the first function with some object.